# Which one is better: 'I'm Dominican and I'm proud' or 'Im Dominican and proud'

Tags: sentence-construction, redundancy

I am going to write a poster regarding a Dominican issue. Which one is better grammatically and naturally?

> I'm Dominican and **I'm proud**

or

> I'm Dominican and **proud**

Comment: None! I'm a proud Dominican! OR I'm a Dominican and I'm proud ***of*** it.

Comment: You could also say "I'm proud to be a Dominican".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'**I'M DOMINICAN**' and '**I'M PROUD**' can be interpreted as two disconnected statements. It may sound fine, but you rather use something to relate these two, say, for example, **'I'M DOMINICAN AND I'M PROUD OF IT'** or **'I'M A DOMINICAN AND I TAKE PRIDE IN IT'**. However, the former makes more sense.

Comment: isn't it good:  I'm a proud Dominican

Comment: Yes. I actually added that in my answer and later took it off before posting it. The reason to do that is, again, 'I'M A PROUD DOMINICAN' can be interpreted in two ways. 1) You're a Dominican and you're proud of it, or 2) You're just a proud guy, who happens to be Dominican. But technically, it is correct. But when you make a poster, make sure it conveys just **ONE** meaning.

Answer (score 2):

**I'm Dominican and I'm proud** would be my choice, as a native US English speaker, because it clearly echoes [James Brown's song "Say It Loud - I'm Black and I'm Proud"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Say_It_Loud_%E2%80%93_I%27m_Black_and_I%27m_Proud), which is a call for Black people to be proud of their racial identity.

Any American hearing the phrase **I'm X and I'm proud** is very likely to relate the phrase to the song and understand it as a statement of racial pride.  I wouldn't necessarily phrase other things that way - for example, "I'm Belgian and I'm tall" or "I'm 34 and I'm a father of two" sounds a little odd, because we wouldn't ordinarily repeat *I'm*, but in the context of racial identity, it is certainly the way to go in the US.

Comment: " I'm a proud Dominican! " does it sound natural?

Comment: @RayanAhmed - Yes, "I'm a proud Dominican!" sounds natural.